# display element of array php

Tags: php, html, printing, echo

I have this PHP/HTML code:

```php
<table>                                                                                        
  <tr>
    <td>Region:</td>
    <td>
      <select style="width:200px" name="region"> 
      <?php for( $i=0;$i<sizeof($regions);$i++) { ?>
      <option value=<?php echo($regions[$i]) ;?>><?php echo( $regions[$i]) ;?></option> 
      <?php }?>
      </select>  
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is the value displayed is `( Array )`. I tried to replace `echo` by `printf` and `sprintf` but I have the same result. But if I replaced it with `print_r` I now have this information `(Array ([0] => Alaska[region] => Alaska)`.

I need to know what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get `Array` as your output, then you're actually doing something like:

```
$x = array();
echo $x;
```

e.g. you're not outputting an ELEMENT of an array, you're trying to output the entire array.

That means `$regions[$i]` is itself an array, and you need a sub-index, e.g. `$regions[$i][1]` instead.

Comment: thanks i replaced it by `$regions[$i][0]` and it is work thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($regions as $region)
      <option value=<?php echo($region['region']) ;?>><?php echo( $region['region']) ;?></option> 
    <?php }?>
```